# Writing a jq to add key names on a json list

Tags: linux, json, jq

I was trying to write a query in linux for alternate a json file and write it in a new file.

**My json file is formatted like so:**

```json
{"intents": [
  {
    "patterns": "'For the last 8 years of his life, Galileo was under house arrest for espousing this man's theory'",
    "responses": "Copernicus"
  },
  {
    "patterns": "'No. 2: 1912 Olympian; football star at Carlisle Indian School; 6 MLB seasons with the Reds, Giants & Braves'",
    "responses": "Jim Thorpe"
  },
```

for about 200k entries like the above.

**The command that I execute is bellow:**

```bash
jq --argjson r \
  "$( jo tag = "$(curl -Ss "https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=0&max=1000000&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new")")" \
  '.intents[] += $r' \
< intents7.json > intents_super.json
```

i was wanted to add a new **keyname** in the list as a **tag** name and i wanted to fill the key(**the tag)** for every entry with a **random number**.
The command was executed but i am waiting like 30 mins so far and nothing is outputting in the file intents_super.json.

**Note:** The cpu is on constant 100%
also in terminal i was getting those 2 lines, the command still running though..:

```
Argument `tag' is neither k=v nor k@v
Argument `17208' is neither k=v nor k@v
```

**Does the command do what I want?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to add a new key, `tag`, to each of the elements of the top-level `intents` array with a random number as value, then you may do this like so:

```bash
some-command | jq -n 'input | .intents |= map(.tag = input)' intents7.json -
```

... where `some-command` is a command that generates an endless stream of random numbers, one per line (for example, `shuf -i 0-100 -r` or `jot -r 0` or similar).

The `jq` command is used with its `-n` option to turn off the normal reading of the input.  Instead, `input` is used to fetch the next object.

The first object is read from the file `intents7.json`, and it contains the `intents` array that we want to modify.  We modify each element of the array by using `map()`.  The expression that we `map` onto each element adds a `tag` key with the value read using `input`.  Each call to `input` (after the very initial one) reads from the standard input stream of `jq`.  On that stream, there are random numbers available, and these are used for the values of the new `tag` keys.

Example run (using a corrected variant of the data in the question):

```bash
$ shuf -i 0-1000 -r | jq -n 'input | .intents |= map(.tag = input)' intents7.json -
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "patterns": "'For the last 8 years of his life, Galileo was under house arrest for espousing this man's theory'",
      "responses": "Copernicus",
      "tag": 517
    },
    {
      "patterns": "'No. 2: 1912 Olympian; football star at Carlisle Indian School; 6 MLB seasons with the Reds, Giants & Braves'",
      "responses": "Jim Thorpe",
      "tag": 955
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thats actually better!! Thanks! and yes i used the dev random

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by another way:

```bash
od -t x -An /dev/random | tr -d " " | fold -w 8 | jq -nRc --slurpfile stream intents7.json '$stream[] .intents[] | .tag=input' > intensfinalllllll.json
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: btw...      od -- octal, decimal, hex, ASCII dump.

The od utility is a filter which displays the specified files, or standard input if no files are specified, in a user specified format.